# How to write a if statement with multiple conditions in multiple lines in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, logical-operators, multiple-conditions

The `if` statement with **multiple conditions** in **one line** below works properly:

```py
exam1 = 70
exam2 = 60
exam3 = 50

if (100 >= exam1 and exam1 >= 60) or (100 >= exam2 and exam2 >= 60) or (100 >= exam3 and exam3 >= 60):
    print("You passed!!")
```

Output:

```
You passed!!
```

But, the `if` statement with **multiple conditions** in **multiple lines** below doesn't work properly:

```py
exam1 = 70
exam2 = 60
exam3 = 50

if (100 >= exam1 and exam1 >= 60) or 
   (100 >= exam2 and exam2 >= 60) or 
   (100 >= exam3 and exam3 >= 60):
    print("You passed!!")
```

Then, I got the error below:

```
File "main.py", line 5
    if (100 >= exam1 and exam1 >= 60) or 
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, how can I write the `if` statement with **multiple conditions** and **multiple lines**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **backslashes** for the `if` statement with **multiple conditions** in **multiple lines** as shown below:

```py
exam1 = 70
exam2 = 60
exam3 = 50
                                   # ↓ Here
if (100 >= exam1 and exam1 >= 60) or \
   (100 >= exam2 and exam2 >= 60) or \
   (100 >= exam3 and exam3 >= 60): # ↑ Here
    print("You passed!!")
```

Then, it works properly as shown below:

```
You passed!!
```